# .ajax cross domain and MySQL do not work correctly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, header, cross-domain

I execute a .ajax request on different domain in particular on sub domain of principal domain after click on button of a registration form, this is the code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://sub.domain.com/query.php?s="+a,
  crossDomain:true,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
   alert(html);
  },
  error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
  },    
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
}
```

In query.php I have 3 header functions php and one query but when this page is called I see in the db 2 records is very strange.

query.php:

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");

$db = mysql_connect('localhost','usr','pwd') or die("Database error"); 
mysql_select_db('dbname', $db); 
$termine=$_GET['s'];
$dati_arr=explode("|", $termine);
$values = array_values($dati_arr);
$query="INSERT INTO tabella VALUES ('','".implode("','", $values)."')";
if(mysql_query($query)){echo "ok";}
?>
```

One query but I find 2 records in the db I can't find the error.

Comment: what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: post the code where you are registering the ajax call with button click. May be you are attaching to an event which is triggered twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing cross origin ajax, the browser may do what's called a [preflight request](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-result-cache0) - it basically does one request with a request method of `OPTIONS` to find out whether the server allows cross origin requests, what http methods are allowed and so on. If that checks out then it does the actual request (and will remember what the result of the `OPTIONS` request was (subject to caching policies) so that next time round it doesn't need to do this.

Your php code doesn't differentiate between the preflight request and the actual 'do-it' request and so inserts the data twice. You should check the http method before taking any action other than sending back the cross origin headers. As an aside it's it bit dodgy for a `GET` request to have side effects.

Answer (score 0):

All is ok with the code you posted. I think it will be more usefull to post all html+js code